# Jasmine test case error 'Spy to have been called'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing jasmine test case for below angular function and getting test case failed message "Expected spy [object Object] to have been called".

```
    $scope.displayTagModelPopup = function() {
        var dialogOptions = {
            templateUrl: 'views/mytags.html',
            controller: 'TagsCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                tagsAvailable: function() {
                    return $scope.availableTags;
                }
            }
        };

        ModalDialogFactory.showDialog(dialogOptions).then(function(result) {
            $scope.selectedFields = [];
            $scope.selectedFieldIds = [];

            angular.forEach(result, function(tag) {
                $scope.selectedFields.push(tag);
                $scope.selectedFieldIds.push(tag.objectId);
            });
        });
    };
```

My Jasmine Test case

```
it('should call displayTagModelPopup', function() {
    var dialogOptions = {
        templateUrl: 'views/mytags.html',
        controller: 'TagsCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        tagsAvailable: [{
            objectId: "c647abc7-f651-4df6-880d-cf9fb69cdcb0",
            dataFieldName: "author",
            shortNamePath: "$.author",
            templates: ["HaM sheet"]
        }]
    };
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy(modalDialogFactory, 'showDialog').and.callFake(function(data) {
        $scope.tags = [{
            objectId: "c647abc7-f651-4df6-880d-cf9fb69cdcb0",
            dataFieldName: "author",
            shortNamePath: "$.author",
            templates: ["HaM sheet"]
        }];
        return $scope.tags;
    });

    $scope.displayTagModelPopup();
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

And getting the below error
"Expected spy [object Object] to have been called.
Error: Expected spy [object Object] to have been called."

what is the issue in my test case?am i missing anything?

Thanks in Advance!!!

***Edited:*** 
Changed my Jasmine test case like below getting different message ''undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ModalDialogFactory.showDialog(dialogOptions).then')'

Tried whether ModelDialogFactory is defined or not  but ModalDialogFactory.showDialog method is defined successfully. 
getting test case failed only when call the method '$scope.displayTagModelPopup();'

```
it('should call displayTagModelPopup', function() {

    spyOn(ModalDialogFactory, 'showDialog').and.callFake(function() {
        $scope.tags = [{
            objectId: "c647abc7-f651-4df6-880d-cf9fb69cdcb0",
            dataFieldName: "author",
            shortNamePath: "$.author",
            templates: ["HaM sheet"]
        }];
        return $scope.tags;
    });
    var dialogOptions = {
        templateUrl: 'views/mytags.html',
        controller: 'TagsCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        tagsAvailable: [{
            objectId: "c647abc7-f651-4df6-880d-cf9fb69cdcb0",
            dataFieldName: "author",
            shortNamePath: "$.author",
            templates: ["HaM sheet"]
        }]
    };
    //expect(ModalDialogFactory).toBeDefined();
    //expect(ModalDialogFactory.showDialog).toBeDefined();

    $scope.displayTagModelPopup();
    $scope.$digest();

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to spy on a method of existing object you should use `spyOn` helper ([docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)):

```
spyOn(modalDialogFactory, 'showDialog').and.callFake(...);
```

As a first parameter it applies an object, and as the second - name of the method. It replaces an existing object's method with a spy object.

To check if spy was called you should pass it to `expect()`:

```
expect(modalDialogFactory.showDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The helper you use `jasmine.createSpy()` is to create a "bare" spy, which could be passed as a callback to ensure it will be called ([docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>)). `jasmine.createSpy()` only applies one parameter which is the name of the spy to be shown in test results, this is why there is no any spy attached to your object.

---

**Update:**

You have a line in the first snippet:

```
ModalDialogFactory.showDialog(dialogOptions).then(function(result) { ... });
```

and as you can see `showDialog()` is followed by `then()`. I assume that original `showDialog()` returns some object with a method `then()`, maybe it's a Promise. But in your test when you spy on a `showDialog()` method, from `callFake()` you do not return anything with `then()` method, therefore the error states that a method is undefined. Spy completely replaced your original method and in conjunction with `callFake()` it recreates original behavior.

So from `callFake()` you should return something that imitates a Promise, for example:

```
spyOn(ModalDialogFactory, 'showDialog').and.callFake(function() {
    // ....
    return {
        then: function (cb) {
             cb($scope.tags);
        }
    };
});
```

Here I return an object which has `then()` method, and when it's called with a function as a parameter, then this function acting like a callback is resolved with a `$scope.tags` value, which could be used inside this callback.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Changed my test case but no luck. I'm not sure but i suspect my $scope.displayTagModelPopup() method was not associating with ModalDialogFactory.showDialog. Please look my edited Section if you  have good time.